# Limit of sequence $\frac{1}{2^n} \sum\limits_\epsilon f(\epsilon_1\lambda+\dots+\epsilon_n\lambda^n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

> Let $0<\lambda<1$ and $f\in C(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Consider
>   $I_{n,\lambda}=\frac{1}{2^n}  \sum\limits_{(\epsilon_1,\dots,\epsilon_n) \in \{-1,1\}^n} f(\epsilon_1\lambda+\dots+\epsilon_n\lambda^n)$.
>   Show that the sequence $(I_{n,\lambda}(f))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ has a limit.

I found this exercise in a book (it is an exercise from ENS Paris), if someone has an idea please share it.

Comment: I know but I could not do it with latex...

Comment: Try `\{` and `\}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the proof of V. Rossetto fixed.

As $f$ is continuous
on the compact $[-R,R]$ with $R=1/(1-\lambda)$, it is uniformly continuous on the compact set $[-R,R]$ and therefore, for every $\varepsilon>0$, there is a $\delta=\delta(\varepsilon)>0$, such that 
$$
|x-y|<\delta \quad\Longrightarrow\quad |f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon,
$$
for all $x,y\in [-R,R]$.

Then let $\varepsilon>0$ and set
$$
S_{n+p}=\frac1{2^{n+p}}\sum_{\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}^{n+p}}
f\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n+p}\epsilon_k\lambda^k\right)
=\frac1{2^{n+p}}\sum_{\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}^{n+p}}
f\left(x_n(\epsilon)+\mu_{n,p}(\epsilon)\right)$$
where 
$x_n(\epsilon)=\sum_{k=1}^n\epsilon_k\lambda^k$ 
and 
$\mu_{n,p}(\epsilon)=\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\epsilon_k\lambda^k$.
We have 
$$\left|\mu_{n,p}(\epsilon)\right|
\leq
\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+p}\lambda^k<\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \lambda^k
=\frac{\lambda^{n+1}}{1-\lambda}.$$
Let $n_0$, such that $\dfrac{\lambda^{n_0+1}}{1-\lambda}<\delta(\varepsilon)$, then 
$$
|\mu_{n,p}(\epsilon)|<\varepsilon, \quad \text{for all $p\in\mathbb N$ and $n\ge n_0$.}
$$

We rewrite 
$$S_n=\frac1{2^{n+p}}\sum_{\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}^{n+p}}
f\left(x_n(\epsilon)\right),$$
and compute  $S_{n+p}-S_n$, for $n\ge n_0$:
$$
|S_{n+p}-S_n|\le
\frac1{2^{n+p}}\sum_{\epsilon\in\{-1,1\}^{n+p}}
\left|f\left(x_n(\epsilon)+\mu_{n,p}(\epsilon)\right)
-f\left(x_n(\epsilon)\right)\right|<2^n\cdot\frac{1}{2^n}\varepsilon=\varepsilon.
$$

Therefore the sequence $(S_n)_n$ is a Cauchy sequence a therefore it converges.

Comment: That is much better than my solution. I have withdrawn it. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Let $S_n=\sum\limits_{k=1}^n\lambda^kX_k$ for $(X_k)$ an i.i.d. Bernoulli sequence, thus, $P[X_k=-1]=P[X_k=1]=\frac12$ for every $k$. Then $I_{n,\lambda}=E[f(S_n)]$. Since $|\lambda|\lt1$, $S_n\to S$ almost surely, where $S=\sum\limits_{k=1}^\infty\lambda^kX_k$ is almost surely finite. For every $n$, $|S_n|\leqslant(1-|\lambda|)^{-1}$ with full probability and $f$ is continuous and bounded on bounded intervals, hence $f(S_n)\to f(S)$ almost surely and $(f(S_n))$ is dominated by a constant. Thus, $E[f(S_n)]\to E[f(S)]$. QED.

Comment: Thank but I do not understand everything .., what is Bernoulli sequence ?

Comment: @Did : being familiar with the examination, probability are not taught at all in these classes. You have to resort to "standard" analysis techniques. Isn't the sequence calculable ? And by the way, aren't the $X_k$ rademacher R.V ? (and not Bernouilli). But that's just a detail

Comment: @BertrandR Yes, I have no knowledge on these subjects. thank ^^

Comment: @Julien "what is Bernoulli sequence" Independent random variables with Bernoulli distribution. Which can either mean that each has distribution P(X=0)=P(X=1)=1/2 or, like here, P(X=-1)=P(X=1)=1/2.

Comment: @BertrandR Happening to be familiar as well with this examination, I wonder if you are not referring to their program as it was a few years ago. Since then, a rather significant amount of probability stuff was added. Anyway, now that the proof is here, one can hide its probabilistic content and translate everything in purely analytical language (another user seems to try to be doing so at the moment). My opinion is that the resulting solution is only less clear and more cumbersome.

Comment: Probability stuff will be part of the curriculum for the examination next year.

Comment: The probabilities are not in my cursus(France).As it will be important next year. I made some research and I finally understood. Thank you.